# Video not recording audio on first attempt only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a UIImagePickerController to get images and video.  I am coming across a strange issue where, when recording video, the first take does not play sound.  Subsequent takes after the first do record sound just fine.  When the app is closed and swiped out of the switcher, the same issue occurs.  Otherwise, after the first attempt, it records sound with video normally.

I have NOT come across this issue testing on an iPad 2 but I have come across this issue, and can repeat it 100% of the time, on two different iPhone 5's.  All devices are running iOS 8.2.

I am testing the playback directly through Apple's recording interface before it brings me back to my app.  I am launching that as such:

```
-(void)imageFromCamera:(NSString *)mediaType
{
    self.mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"camera"] || [mediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) self.mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    else self.mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"video"])
    {
        self.mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        [self.mediaPicker setVideoMaximumDuration:30.0f];
    }

    self.mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    self.mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:self.mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When you take video you have the option of checking it right then and there before returning to the app so, besides my launching the picker, this is happening directly in Apple's framework.  This does not happen, however, if I exit the app and record through the Apple camera application.  Also, the app can play video without issue the first time so this is just with recording and again only with these iPhone 5's and not the iPad 2 I also have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  Elsewhere in the app I make use of AVAudio and I have a "prepareToRecord" set.  This is for an ability to record audio messages.  This appears to be interfering with the first attempt to record video in the picker.  Why that doesn't happen on the iPad is a bit of a mystery.  However, removing the prepareToRecord solved this problem.

Comment: Yes, but the system doesn't allow it for 24 hours.  I'll have to come back tomorrow or so before it will allow me to accept it.